# How to use GDCM in Qt

Tags: qt, gdcm

I was compiling GDCM with CMake-GUI, then I tried to create a project in Qt to try the examples.

However when I compile the project, I receive errors.

Let me know if in the .pro file I must include something. I am working on Windows 7.

Comment: can you explain bit more, like what error you are getting...

Comment: I don't know what to do to use GDCM on Qt after I compiling it with CMake-GUI. I want know if I have to include something in the .pro file, tell me please. I'm using Windows 7 OS and Qt 5.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this on *.pro file and I solved the problem:

```
.
.
.
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Qt\GDCM\include\gdcm-2.5  # path .h file

LIBS += -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib" \
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmMSFF.a" \
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmCommon.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmDICT.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmDSED.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmexpat.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmIOD.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmjpeg8.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmjpeg12.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmjpeg16.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmopenjpeg.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmzlib.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmcharls.a"\
        -L"C:\Qt\GDCM\lib\libgdcmgetopt.a"

LIBS += -lgdcmMSFF -lgdcmCommon \
        -lgdcmDICT -lgdcmDSED \
        -lgdcmexpat -lgdcmIOD \
        -lgdcmjpeg8 -lgdcmjpeg12 \
        -lgdcmjpeg16 -lgdcmopenjpeg \
        -lgdcmzlib -lgdcmcharls -lgdcmgetopt
.
.
.
```